# Jenkins withMaven and maven-deploy-plugin behaviour changed

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins, maven-deploy-plugin

I have upgraded a spring-boot api from version 2.6.10 to 3.1.2 (implicitely maven-deploy-plugin was updated from 2.8.2 to 3.1.1).
I use a Jenkins job with the withMaven plugin to run a shell command mvn deploy to deploy a built artifact to Nexus repository.

```
withMaven(maven: 'Maven', jdk: 'Java17') {
    sh 'mvn clean deploy'
}
```

Then in the Jenkins job I use the following code to generate the url to the artifact in Nexus for further processing:

```
def getGeneratedArtifactUrl(String baseUrl) {
    def artifactUrl = ''
    Collection<MavenArtifact> generatedArtifacts = currentBuild.rawBuild.getAction(MavenReport.class).getGeneratedArtifacts()
    for (MavenArtifact generatedArtifact : generatedArtifacts) {


        String shortDescription = generatedArtifact.getShortDescription()
        echo "ShortDescription: ${shortDescription}"

        echo "ArtifactId: ${generatedArtifact.getArtifactId()}"
        echo "Extension: ${generatedArtifact.getExtension()}"
        echo "FileName: ${generatedArtifact.getFileName()}"
        echo "GroupId: ${generatedArtifact.getGroupId()}"
        echo "Version: ${generatedArtifact.getVersion()}"
        echo "BaseVersion: ${generatedArtifact.getBaseVersion()}"
        echo "Extension: ${generatedArtifact.getExtension()}"


        if (shortDescription.contains('tar.gz') || shortDescription.contains('zip')) {


            def groupId = generatedArtifact.getGroupId().replace('.', '/')
            def artifactId = generatedArtifact.getArtifactId()
            def baseversion = generatedArtifact.getBaseVersion()
            def filename = generatedArtifact.getFileName()

            def url = baseUrl.replaceAll('/$', '')
            artifactUrl = "$url/$groupId/$artifactId/$baseversion/$filename"


        }

    }
    return artifactUrl
}
```

Before the upgrade, the MavenArtifact.getFileName() method gave me the exact filename of the deployed artifact (StandardPipelineTest-1.0.5-20230814.123101-6-bin.zip for example).

After upgrading however, getFileName() shows a different filename: StandardPipelineTest-1.0.5-SNAPSHOT-bin.zip. This file however can't be downloaded from Nexus.

After downgrading the maven-deploy-plugin to version 2.8.2 (which comes with spring-boot 2.6.10) the problem was resolved.

How can I use maven-deploy-plugin 3.1.1 (or MavenArtifact methods) to get the version I want (including date and time)? FYI, the MavenArtifact.getFileNameWithVersion() does not give me what I want.